# TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: black

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am new to the turtle graphic library and write the following code. When I executed the below code it runs fine. But if I re-executed it, it gives the bad color string error.

```
import turtle
loss = tortle.Turtle()
loss.color("black")
loss.up()
loss.goto(0,100)
loss.down()
loss.write("Welcome !",False, "center",font = ("Arial Narrow",30,"bold"))
turtle.done()
```

Following error is prompted up

```
TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: black
```

What am I doing wrong? or What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In `color`, you can only use RGB, for above use case, you can use `pencolor`.

[Ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#color-control)

Comment: This is incorrect as it's the wrong documentation reference.  See the [documentation for `color()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.color) where `'black'` is valid.  And it's an incorrect interpretation of the documentation for `pencolor()` (see *colorstring*.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code and your error don't match.  The first error that occurs in the above code is a Python error since `loss` isn't defined:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    loss.color("black")
NameError: name 'loss' is not defined
```

You can fix this, and make the code work, by adding a line after your `import`:

```
import turtle
loss = turtle.Turtle()
```

How I might have written this code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

loss = Turtle()
loss.hideturtle()
loss.penup()
loss.sety(100)
loss.write("Welcome!", align='center', font=('Arial Narrow', 30, 'bold'))

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Sorry for that, I wrote it in my code but forgot to add it here. Thanks, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

When you were defining loss you put: `loss = tortle.Turtle` when it should of been `loss = turtle.Turtle`. I think this just a typo though.
Or you could do `import turtle as tortle` and then change your code to:

```
import turtle as tortle
loss = tortle.Turtle()
loss.color("black")
loss.up()
loss.goto(0,100)
loss.down()
loss.write("Welcome !",False, "center",font = ("Arial 
Narrow",30,"bold"))
tortle.done()
```